# Can we have multiple actions in a single XACML request, if yes how?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, pdp

Consider I am having following sample xacml request. How can i modify the same to evaluate on multiple decisions on multiple actions.

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"
        IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Resource</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes
    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
        IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Subject</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
        IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Action</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, this is a textbook of using Multiple Decision requests as defined in the XACML v3.0 Multiple Decision Profile Version 1.0 ([standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-multiple-v1-spec-cd-03-en.html) | [blog](http://www.axiomatics.com/blog/entry/authoring-multiple-decision-profile-requests-2.html) post).

All you need to do is repeat the Action category several times (the `<Attributes/>` element) i.e. repeat this entire element:

```
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">View</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
```

And just change the attributes inside i.e. add/remove as many `<Attribute/>` elements inside as you like.

```
<xacml-ctx:Request ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false" xmlns:xacml-ctx="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Edit</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Alice</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">View</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Resource</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
</xacml-ctx:Request>
```

In the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point, this is what it looks like:

[image: Simulation of a Multiple Decision Request in Axiomatics]